# Android - how to delete last 2 lines from String?

Tags: java, android, string

I have a String which always looks like this:

---

```
data
data
data
data
non-data
non-data
```

---

And I need to delete the 2 last lines from it. The lenght of these lines can be different. How I can do that fast (String = ~1000 lines)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int lastNewLineAt = string.lastIndexOf("\n");
string.subString(0, string.lastIndexOf("\n", lastNewLineAt));
```

You can use constant for new line character reading system property

Answer (score 3):

I'd say something along the lines of:

```
String[] lines = input.split("\n");
String[] dataLines = Arrays.copyOfRange(lines, 0, lines.length - 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

This Code will split your text by "\n" 's which means your lines in to a String Array.
Than you will get that array's length..

And in a for loop you will set and append your text till your length-1 element.

This may be a long approach but I was searching this and I couldn't find anything. 
This was my easiest way.

```
String[] lines = YourTextViev.getText().toString().split("\n");

YourTextView.setText("");      // clear your TextView
int Arraylength = lines.length-1;    // Changing "-1" will change which lines will be deleted

for(int i=0;i<Arraylength;i++){

    YourTextView.append(lines[i]+"\n");
}
```